# Should I post a question with the answer I already know?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki, self-answer, instant-self-answer

For example, I've have just solved some problem on my own. I believe my solution might be quite useful to others (and myself in the future), like a KB article.

Should I post it as question and answer it myself and mark as community wiki? I'm not interested in extra points in this case.

Comment: Yes. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: See at the bottom of the ask question page? That checkbox next to **Answer your own question**?

Comment: There is no need to mark it community wiki, but you can if you really really wish (it'll make me sad though, good answers marked as community wiki always make me sad)

Comment: When doing this however, remember that the question and answer will be judged seperately, write them as if two people are writing them; self answers are difficult, but when done well can be the best Q&As

Comment: I was curious about the perception of such act by the community, but I understand now it's expected to be positive (depending on the question, I guess :) Thanks for your thoughts.